# Internet Explorer Personal Certificate Store

Tags: internet-explorer, certificate

I've noticed that certificates imported into a current user's personal store either through the mmc snap-in or programmatically will not show up in Internet Explorer's personal certificate store for the same current user if I browse certificates via IE's content tab under Tools/Internet Options.

Are these not the same stores? If not why? How do I programmatically set a current user's certificate into IE's store?

The .net X509Store class doesn't seem to work for IE imports.  I'm trying to import a certificate for client authentication without having to go through the manual prompts of IE.

Also: is there a way to import the certificate for all user IE sessions programmatically or am I stuck doing it for only the currently logged on user?

Comment: Several questions, but I see no coding attempt?

Comment: Primarily, this isn't a coding question. I'm wanting to know why the personal certificates for the current user shows in the personal certificate store via the mmc snap-in but not for the same user in the IE personal certificate store.  They do appear to be the same store because I can import through IE and refresh the mmc snap-in and see my cert added but not the other way around.  The CA cert is in the trusted root CA store, if that mattered.

Comment: "Primarily, this isn't a coding question." - then it does not belong on StackOverflow.

Comment: I should also note I unfiltered intended purposes so that shouldn't be the issue afaik.

Comment: "then it does not belong on StackOverflow" - I guess you can copy and paste that into 80% of the issues.  Thanks anyway

Comment: actually the bit I copy and pasted was straight from your comment: "Primarily, this isn't a coding question." - it doesn't get much clearer than that! Try Superuser.com

Comment: great. thanks for clarification and redirect.